# How can I query for a Test Folder in Rally Rest tookit for Java?

Tags: java, rally

Here is the basic code i am attempting to use:

```
  //create new QueryRequest
  QueryRequest tests = new QueryRequest("Test Case");

  //Gets the information from QueryFilter
  tests.setFetch(new Fetch("FormattedID","Name","Owner","Test Folder"));

  //checks to see if the test Case's test folder matches the given one
  testFolderFilter =  new QueryFilter("Test Folder", "=", testFolder);

  // set query filter
  tests.setQueryFilter(testFolderFilter); 

  // Query Rally
  QueryResponse queryResponse = restApi.query(tests);
```

I have sucessfully done it using the `Name` and `FormattedID` in place of `Test Folder` so I assume I just need to use a different string for `Test Folder`. Any suggestions are welcome.

Examples were of no help to me but they can be found at: http://www.rallydev.com/developer/java-toolkit-rally-rest-api

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code looks great, this should work for you with the following minor change to your query syntax:

```
  testFolderFilter = new QueryFilter("TestFolder.Name", "=", testFolder);
```

A handy place to test your query syntax interactively before running in code is the Rally webservices API documentation:

https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/doc/webservice/

Each artifact has a handy "Query" dialog that lets you run example query syntax to see what works and what doesn't.

Comment: Thank you on a realated note if you are still willing to help; I also need to add a new test case with a test folder property can i use the same "TestFolder.Name" as in:  
JsonObject newTest = new JsonObject();
newTest.addProperty("TestFolder.Name", "thisTestFolder");
CreateRequest createRequest = new CreateRequest("Test Case", newTest);

Comment: Almost. The TestFolder property has to be set to the ref of the relevant TestFolder object in Rally, i.e.: newTestCase.addProperty("TestFolder", "/testfolder/12345678910"); where the long integer is the ObjectID (OID) of the testfolder in Rally. You can get the full ref URL of the  by doing an additional query for the TestFolder of interest and pulling the reference off of the response.

Comment: Thank you I have that in working order, you have been a huge help. I just have one last question; do tags work the same as test folders? to add one i query then use the ref string with addProperty to add to a testCase? .addProperty("Tag", "/Tag/12345678910"); assuming the Tag exists of course.

Comment: Tags are a bit trickier because they are a collection and you have to update them as an array of JSON objects. I'll see if I can work up a simple example and post as a 2nd answer.